# How to get dotnet environment variables from os env?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, environment-variables, .net-6.0

I am using .NET 6 project. I have application settings in `appsettings.json` like this:

```
{
  "ClusterSettings": {
      "Host": "machine1",
      "Password": "1222"
  }
}
```

I want to delete Password from the json and use it from Windows environment variables. I am settings a Windows environment variable: `ClusterSettings__Password` (using double underscore)

I am getting the value using a class in Startup.cs

```
Conf = new Settings();
Configuration = builder.Build();
Configuration.Bind(Config);
```

Settings  class:

```
public class Settings{
  public ClusterSettings { get;set;}
}

public class ClusterSettings 
{
   public string Host {get;set;}
   public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

But the application does not get the variable from Windows. How can I get it?

Comment: Try Environment.ExpandEnvironmentalVariables, and related...

Comment: You forgot to post the code that reads the value of the environment variable...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0 is this what you are looking for?

Comment: If you added env variable during development, you need to restart VS to make it read new env variables, since debug is launched in the context of VS. I tried it myself and since I don't restart Visual Studio new env variables are not loaded. Anyway I suggest to use [user secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=windows) (in dev environment) for stuffs like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the application does not get the variable from Windows. How can I
> get it?

Actually, it would be great if you could share how you are trying to extract your appsettings.json value within your .NET6 app.

However, depending on the scenario it can be retrieve from program.cs file and controller level as well.

Let's have a look in practice how we can get it on either environment.

Program.cs:

Way:1

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var clusterSettingsPass = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ClusterSettings:Password");
```

Way:2

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
var clusterSettings = configuration.GetValue<string>("ClusterSettings:Host");
```

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Following the same way, you can get the password or any other property as well.

Controller Level:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _appSettingsValue;
        private string clusterSettings;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _appSettingsValue = configuration;
            clusterSettings = _appSettingsValue["ClusterSettings:Host"]!;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var getAppSettingsValue = clusterSettings;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can [refer to this sample](https://github.com/kironiitdu/ExtractAppSettingsValue). If you would like to know more details on [configuration providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#application-configuration-providers) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#application-configuration-providers).

Comment: updated the post Settings class.

Comment: Thanks for your response, try the solution I provided, it will work accordingly.

Comment: thanks for solution, vs restart needed.